# Microsoft graph - Unable to get thumbnails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have problem with OneDrive thumbnails.

I'm authorised as admin, I have all neccesary permissions, so I'm able to search user files and download them, edit and so on, but when I'm trying to bind thumbnail url to image src I'm getting error:

```
{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The access token is not a valid token issued by SP: nameid ...}
```

And my query is:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/drive/root?$expand = thumbnails, children($expand = thumbnails($select = medium))
```

Do you have any solution? For first approach I was logging in from javascript and had to type a password every time, but everything worked fine